# JS - my loop using setTimeout stops looping

Tags: javascript

I have the following code :

```
var i = 0, count = 10, randomId;

    function f(myArray) {

          // this will get a random value from myArray
        randomId = myArray[Math.floor( Math.random()*myArray.length )]; 

          // displays the random value
        alert (randomId);


        i++;
        if( i < count ){
            setTimeout( f, 3000 );
        }
    }

    f(myArray);
```

The above code works but gives only one alert and then it stops.

However it works properly (10 loops) with basic alerts such as `alert("hi")`, and remove the randomId line.

It's as if anything complex within this function will block the loop, it will only handle basic alerts..

Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: You're calling `f(myArray)`, but where is `myArray`? Your recursive call doesn't pass anything to `f`, so it will be `undefined`, thus creating an error when you do `myArray.length`

Comment: myArray was created previously. So the first alert will work fine, returning eg. 42

Comment: Then do `setTimeout(f, 3000, myArray)`

Comment: Nvm now i understand it, thanks !

Comment: ...just be aware that it won't work in old IE and old Firefox. To support those, you'd need `setTimeout(function() { f(myArray) }, 3000)`

Comment: Also, you should move i++ to after the if check.  From what you have here you should only expect 9 iterations (assuming the other issue is fixed).

Answer (score 3):

In your `setTimeout` you are not passing the array:

Try this:

```
    if( i < count ){
        setTimeout(() => f(myArray), 3000 );
    }
```

^ that creates a lambda function so that you can pass a value to your callback in the timeout.

```js
var i = 0, count = 10, randomId;

    function f(myArray) {

          // this will get a random value from myArray
        randomId = myArray[Math.floor( Math.random()*myArray.length )]; 

          // displays the random value
        alert (randomId);


        i++;
        if( i < count ){
            setTimeout(() => f(myArray), 3000 );
        }
    }

    f([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]);
```

Comment: it is ok but it will fail it  browser does not support ES6.

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz true. in those browsers you can just use `function () { f(myArray); }` instead, or use a transpiler :-)